# Amazon s3 - Call file after upload

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using a php script to upload a file to Amazon S3

```
$s3->putObjectFile($url,$bucket,$filename, S3::ACL_PRIVATE,array(),array("Content-Type" => "application/json"));
```

Immediately after the upload, I need to get some information from the file and I call it through Cloudfront but I see that the file is available only after some minutes.

Do you know why and if there is a way to sort this out?
Is there a way to have the file immediately available?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It was immediately available for me with this test...

```
$ date;aws s3 cp foo s3://BUCKET/foo;date;curl -I http://dxxx.cloudfront.net/foo;date

Thu Aug  6 04:30:01 UTC 2015
upload: ./foo to s3://BUCKET/foo
Thu Aug  6 04:30:02 UTC 2015
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 24
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Thu, 06 Aug 2015 04:30:03 GMT
x-amz-version-id: null
Last-Modified: Thu, 06 Aug 2015 04:30:03 GMT
ETag: "5089fc210a3df99a6a04fe64c929d8e7"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 fed2ed9d8e7c2b37559eac3b2a2386fc.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: gEaAkLCqstyAdakXkBvMmSJVrfKjKTD5K9WoyZBHvVZufWuuhclNLQ==

Thu Aug  6 04:30:02 UTC 2015
```

Perhaps your upload is happening asynchronously and the upload hadn't completed yet?